# Why isn't my computer turning on?

Tags: power

I did a test boot with just the CPU and power supply hooked up to the motherboard.  I tried to short the 2 power pins on the motherboard, but that didn't work.  However, when I shorted all of the pins, the fans spun up and I got a POST beep.  I proceeded to put everything in the case and power it on.  However, it doesn't power on when I press the power button on the case.  I have the power cords from the case plugged in, as well as the reset and HDD LED cords.  Any ideas on why it's not booting?

No fans ever spin up fully, however one of the case fans kind of jolts about 3/4 times that I press the power on button on the case.

Comment: Do this as a small test. This is totally safe. Anything outside the PSU Box is DC and not high voltage or current. If you're worried you can do this(sticking the paperclip in) while no power goes to the PSU. Take a paperclip, bend it, stick it so one end goes in the green and one end goes in a black. That should turn the power supply on. You can do this when the power supply is not connected to the motherboard. Does it go on constantly? Connect it to a fan, does it move a fan? (I suppose it should move the fan)

Comment: Is this a rebuilt computer or a new one? As in, are there any parts that are older that may need replacing?

Comment: @barlop I did that.  It worked. ||| Christopher: it's a new build.

Comment: In your Q you mention that you shorted all the pins. How? What did you do to do that? Try shorting all the pins again, does it go on consistently? Narrow down what pins need to be shorted to get it on consistently.  Maybe not all need to be shorted. Maybe you connected the power on button to the wrong pins. Check the motherboard manual for the pin numbers and which to connect it to

Comment: I just layed a screwdriver over all of them.  I'm trying to figure out which pins work now.

Comment: What motherboard?

Comment: Asus P8Z68-V LX

Comment: I called Asus.  They told me the motherboard was probably bad.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin  you could take a small wire strip the ends and touch one end on one pin, then drag the other end over other pins. that may be a quick way to try to find what pins - if any 2, to connect to get it on. But bad motherboard seems likely..'cos your symptoms don't seem normal at all.. that it doesn't routinely turn on only sometimes. And that your power supply on a basic test, seemed to turn on fine every time.

Comment: @barlop It turns out that I had to short one of the LED pins and a power pin for it to work....  Strange, but I got it to work!  I'm typing this on my new build!

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin great. out of interest, are the two pins adjacent? like next to each other? or across from each other?  and did you have a jumper that managed to cover them both?

Comment: They were a few pins away and diagonal from each other.  The diagram in the mobo manual was wrong and I had to plug the LED connector into a different pin.  I felt really dumb when I figured it out 'cause I had driven 2 hours to exchange my mobo when it wasn't even the problem. xD

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin  that sounds wild, how did you discover exactly what 2, did you use the technique I mentioned in my comment? or another technique?  not dumb at all considering it also has asus thinking you should take the mbrd back, or, that they didn't realise the issue was just with connecting 2 different pins. As far as having a permanent way to conveniently turn your computer on/off goes, did your power switch have 2* 1-pin jumpers so you can put the wires on pins that aren't adjacent or do you use some other method to connect them, if so, what method?

Comment: I used a paper clip to figure it out.  I had to plug the HDD LED connector into that pin.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin not sure what you mean about plugging the HDD LED connector onto a particular pin or pins http://attachments.techguy.org/attachments/127977d1204851157/kk-connectors.jpg but anyhow it's worth you posting your solution as an answer also when commenting to reply to somebody you should write @... as that way they get notified. They also get notified if it's a comment on a question they wrote,or a comment on an answer they wrote.So technically I don't have to put an @ when commenting and addressing you 'cos you get the notification.But if you address somebody else here they wouldn't